# Should we expect oauth in GAE to support more openID providers in the future?

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, oauth

This isn't a programming question per se, but I'm hoping someone here will notice it and have an answer, I already tried the GAE group but got nothing.

I'm working on an app where the GAE component will be an oauth providor, and a mobile client will be the oauth consumer.  For logging into the web app, I want to use openid, but right now built in support for oauth is limited to google as the openid providor, which sort of defeats the purpose of openid.  This is ok for the time being if I can expect GAE's oauth implementation to eventually support other openid providors, but I have no idea if thats a reasonable expectation!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing things a bit. Google is not the only OpenId provider that you can use. [This article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html) shows examples of OpenId authentication using MySpace, Yahoo, AOL, MyOpenId.com and of course Google, but you can use any provider that you want, really.

Comment: Nope.  I know this is a bit confusing, but if you look here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/overview.html#OAuth_and_App_Engine
I quote: "The user must have a Google account to sign in and authorize a consumer. If an app uses federated logins (OpenID), the user is sent directly to Google Accounts to sign in to authorize a consumer. Other OpenID identity providers are not supported for OAuth authentication."

Comment: Ah I see. Federated login is Google-only indeed. However you can use any OpenId provider for non-federated auth. This thing is pretty new though, a couple of months or something, and I think it'll be improved.